# How to use a provide an immutable, thread-safe list via an Observer?

Tags: multithreading, list, kotlin

I use StackOverflow quite a bit but haven't asked many questions since I always find an answer somewhere. However, for this dilemma, I can't seem to find a good solution.

So here goes.

I'm building a library in Kotlin. And I'm using an observer pattern.

I have a class listening to incoming messages coming from a 3rd party service, parsing those messages and enqueueing/adding the parsed objects in a mutable list. The list could be modified at any time.

Meanwhile, any subscribed observers can be notified when changes are done to the list. Right now, I have it setup so that the list is one of parameters in my Observer methods.

Since I'm not using Google's Guava library or the KotlinX library, because I want to keep this library as light as possible, I wrote a small implementation of ImmutableList as follows:

```
class ImmutableList<T>(list: MutableList<T>) : List<T> by list

// Extension to MutableList<T>
fun <T> MutableList<T>.toImmutableList() = ImmutableList(this)
```

I got the idea for the above from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50648717/kotlin-custom-get-immutable-list-from-mutablelist)

With this code, my goal is to enforce passing an immutable list that is thread-safe.

One of my observer method definitions looks like this:

```
fun notifyListChanged(list: List<Something>)
```

And when I send an update to my observer, I do something like this

```
observer.notifyListChanged(myMutableList.toImmutableList())
```

**So my questions:**

By doing this, can I ensure that the list I'm sending is both immutable and thread-safe?

I realize that the underlying list can still change at anytime, causing the list I send and the actual list to get out of sync. That's why I'm using an observer model for updates to the list. Since I want to avoid exposing the underlying list outside of the library, is this the best way to achieve my goals?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By doing this, can I ensure that the list I'm sending is both immutable and thread-safe?

No, the list you're sending is neither immutable, nor thread-safe because, as you correctly noted, the underlying `MutableList` can change at any time later.

To fix the content of your `ImmutableList`, you should make a defensive copy of its items:

```
class ImmutableList<T>(list: List<T>) : List<T> { ... }

// Extension to MutableList<T>
fun <T> MutableList<T>.toImmutableList() = ImmutableList(this.toList())
```

Another problem here is that implementing `ImmutableList<T>` class using the interface delegation `by list` doesn't produce a correct implementation of `List<T>` type: its `hashCode`, `equals`, and `toString` methods are not delegated; instead they inherit their default implementation from `Any`, thus violating `List` interface contract.

You can use the interface delegation, but then you should delegate these 3 methods manually. Also it's worth to write a manual implementation of `subList` that also wraps the returned sublist into `ImmutableList` to prevent it being modified from the outside.

Comment: Thanks Ilya. 
I ended up taking your suggestion, but keeping the interface delegation and overriding the `hashCode`, `equals`, `toString` and `subList` methods as you suggested.